# Ruby, how can i compare a string with a specific element of array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I create an array from a text file which contains the english irregular verbs. I want the code to ask me the verbs in random order letting me proceed only if I respond correctly. I need to compare a string with an element of array. I wrote this:

```
a = []
File.open('documents/programmi_test/verbi.txt') do |f|
  f.lines.each do |line|
    a <<line.split.map(&:to_s)
  end
end
puts ''
b = rand(3)
puts a[b][0]
puts 'infinitive'
infinitive = gets.chomp
  if infinitive = a[b][1]    #--> write like this, I receive alway "true"
    puts 'simple past'
  else
    puts 'retry'
  end
pastsimple = gets.chomp
  if pastsimple == a[b][2]    #--> write like this, I receive alway "false"
    puts 'past participle'
  else
    puts 'retry'
  end
pastpart = gets.chomp
  if pastpart == a[b][3]
    puts 'compliments'
  else
    puts 'oh, no'
  end
```

can somebody help me?

Comment: Please provide a better expected result to go by, and have you tried anything? If so please provide that as well.

Comment: If the code asks to me to write the infinitive of the verb "battere" (position [0] of the array [b], in the text file it's the position [0] of the array [1]), I have to write "beat" (position [1] of the array [1]) to go on. If I write something else, I have to try again.

Answer (score 1):

`if infinitive = a[b][1]` is assigning to inifinitive the value of `a[b][1]`, unlike `pastsimple == a[b][2]` that's a comparation between both values.

You could try replacing the `=` for `==`.

```
a = []

File.open('documents/programmi_test/verbi.txt') do |file|
  file.lines.each do |line|
    a << line.split.map(&:to_s)
  end
end

puts ''
b = rand(3)
puts a[b][0]
puts 'infinitive'

infinitive = gets.chomp
puts infinitive == a[b][1] ? 'simple past' : 'retry'
pastsimple = gets.chomp
puts pastsimple == a[b][2] ? 'past participle' : 'retry'
pastpart = gets.chomp
puts pastpart == a[b][3] ? 'compliments' : 'oh, no'
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the code doesn't compare the "infinitive" with the string in the file that is in the position [1]  of the [b] (random) array

Comment: You need to debug such values, using byebug you can check them easily.